# Is there any way we can put formula multiple bases on range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say I have

```
0.5     600
1       865
1.5     900
2       1000
2.5     1200
3       1356
3.5     1500
```

if(B2 == Range B50:B60) if matches then multiple by C2

Lets says I put 1 into B2 so it should calculate 1*865 if I change the value 1.5 then it should calculate by 1.5*900 how this is possible please guide

Thanks

Comment: Use `VLOOKUP`, `INDEX+MATCH`, `XLOOKUP` or even `SUMIF`. What have you tried?

Comment: =SUMIF(B6:B12,B2,C6*B6)

Comment: You are mixing a lot of different ranges but looks like you want `=B2*SUMIF(B6:B12,B2,C6:C12)`

Comment: YES true I fixed thank you